# How to automatically type pre-defined text with a simple command on IOS?

Tags: script, automation, siri, copy-paste, shortcuts-app

On IOS 14.4 or above, is there any way to automate/simulate the process of entering text into the currently focused textfield, (even a password textfield)?

In an ideal world, with the text cursor blinking, you could just say, "Hey Siri, type string_5" where string_5 has been predefined as your email address or password, **for example*****... or maybe use some kind of keyboard plug-in.

But you can't do that at the moment... or can you??

What I've tried so far:

1. The "Paste It" keyboard app.

Result: Doesn't work / app is seemingy broken.  Even if it did work, for some asinine reason, it needs internet access and "the developer can see whatever you type."  No thanks.  If there were a keyboard app with this feature... that doesn't use the internet, and also works, that would be nice.

2. The Text Replacement feature of IOS, such that, for example, typing "ezpz" results in "mysuperlongemailaddress@place.com" being entered.

Result: Works well, but this technique won't work for password fields.

3. The Shortcuts app.

Result: I haven't found a way of accomplishing what I'm trying to do.  I know the Shortcuts app can do scripting and all kinds of stuff so many it's possible?

4. Just telling Siri, "type [the stuff I want to type]" or "paste [stuff]."

Result: Either it doesn't work at all or she thinks I want to send a text message.  Siri doesn't understand "type into the currently focused textfield."

*** - The username/password use case is just an example.  Password managers are of no use to me.  I don't want to use one and also I'm using Microsoft Edge, so I don't think they would work, anyway.

Comment: If you want to simplify password entry, a password manager or iCloud Keychain might be an option.

Comment: What you are trying to do with password entry is literally why password managers were invented in the first place. For all other places I'd use the text replacement.

Comment: I editted the question

Comment: If you're ok with non-official apps try Clip. It's a clipboard manager so you have your copy history at hand.

Comment: If you are looking for a more powerful version of the built-in text replacement feature, you might want to look at [TextExpander](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/textexpander-keyboard/id1075927186) (commercial and rather pricey – this is not an endorsement). Note that, like all third party text expansion tools, it relies on a keyboard extension to work in other apps. For security reasons, iOS will not allow third party keyboards to work in password fields; the only integration with these is via the password manager API (hence the recommendations above).